# JSON_VALUE usage in H2 database

Tags: java, spring-boot, h2

In application code, we are using JSON_VALUE function for getting particular value from stored json.

```
SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE JSON_VALUE(ADDR_JSON, '$.pinCode') != '390018'
```

When we are writing functional test cases which uses H2 database, it is resulting into following error:

> nested exception is java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: user lacks privilege or object not found: JSON_VALUE in statement

Can you please suggest if anyone has some solution on this ?

Answer (score 1):

At the time of this writing, Shakirov's answer is correct - H2 does not have a built in function to access JSON attributes. However, you can create a [user defined function](https://h2database.com/html/features.html#user_defined_functions) using whatever JSON library you want. Example:

```
CREATE ALIAS JSON_VALUE AS '
String jsonValue(String json, String key) {

    //Implement your code here and return a string

    return "";
}
';
```

Another option is to cast the JSON data to a string and use the built in REGEXP_SUBSTR to parse the data and return what you want. If your JSON is simple enough, you can try something like this:

```
/"name"(\s*?:{1}\s*?)"(.*?)"/g
```

Where "name" is the key you're looking for. You can test the regex [here](https://regex101.com/r/FONaIT/1). Obviously you shouldn't use regex for complex JSON.

Comment: I tried implementing the JSON_VALUE function in H2 but if I specify any option after the 2nd argument, a syntax error occurs. How do I support these? I'm trying to not have to change the production code's queries (uses MySQL).

Comment: In the end we made do with modifying the queries to not use these options. To get a default value in case of null we wrap the `JSON_VALUE` function in an `IFNULL`, and we handle all returned values as strings even though it's ugly... I guess there was no way to handle these options. Isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

H2 does not support accessing JSON attributes. See here for a list of supported functions: https://www.h2database.com/html/functions.html